# Backup Agent doesn't work with my app based on Realm database

Tags: java, android, realm

I used Google Backup Agent to backup the notes on my app. I tried to backup the Realm database, but it didn't work. I used this type of backup with SQLite database and it works fine, but I don't know how to get the Realm database correctly to backup it.

*** MyBackupAgent.java:**

```
import android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper;
import android.app.backup.BackupDataInput;
import android.app.backup.BackupDataOutput;
import android.app.backup.BackupManager;
import android.app.backup.FileBackupHelper;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

    private String KEY = "key";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        addHelper(KEY, new FileBackupHelper(this, "//data//data//com.twitter.i_droidi.notah//files//Notes"));
    }

    private void requestBackup()
    {
        BackupManager bm = new BackupManager(this);
        bm.dataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public File getFilesDir() {
        File path = getDatabasePath("//data//data//com.twitter.i_droidi.notah//files//Notes");
        return path.getParentFile();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data, ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
        super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode, ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
        super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#how-to-back-up-and-restore-realm

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks. I tried it on the emulator, but didn't work. I will try it on a real device.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I tried it also on my device, and it didn't work! I used this code `RealmController.getInstance().getRealm().getPath()` instead of `"//data//data//com.twitter.i_droidi.notah//files//Notes"`.

Comment: ....a Realm that you back up should be closed, all instances on all threads

Comment: That includes the UI thread Realm that you probably open and then never close in `RealmController`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I tried to close it, but the log shows `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm instance can only be closed on the thread it was created.`

Comment: Well you should close it on the same thread as where it was opened...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It opened in many activities.. so I need to close it in every activity in `onDestroy();` and reopen it in `onCreate();`?!

Comment: Of course. [The docs say so.](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances) Although [I personally prefer having a single global UI thread Realm instance.](https://github.com/Zhuinden/wikilight/commit/5514902afb8ee8adc4be150abf684ccef9d379bf)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I tried before to open it in `onCreate();` and close it in `onDestroy();`. But when I come back to the MainActivity (for example: MainActivity.java -> CreateNote.java -> MainActivity.java). The app stops and says the realm is closed. Hint: I use this line of code for opening `this.realm = RealmController.with(this).getRealm();`.

Comment: Well `RealmController` doesn't actually come from Realm, does it?

Comment: Or you can consider to use `Realm.writeCopyTo()`. It doesn't requires you to close all instance. See https://realm.io/docs/java/1.2.0/api/io/realm/Realm.html#writeCopyTo-java.io.File-